# CDI global event handling in JSF (javax.enterprise.event)

Tags: java, events, jsf-2, cdi

I want to implement event handlers based on the `javax.enterprise.event.Event` interface. Currently it works well, but is only limited to a single session. My environment is *JBoss-7.1.1.Final* and *JSF2*. I can demonstrate the issue in this simplified (working) example:

Inside a `@Named` Bean I've defined a `Event<MyEjb>` and can fire events.

```
@Inject private Event<MyEJB> ejbChanged;

public void test()
{
  ejbChanged.fire(new MyEjb());
}
```

This is recognized in a `@Named @SessionScoped` Bean and I can easily process this

```
public void
       onChanged(@Observes(notifyObserver = Reception.IF_EXISTS) final MyEjb ejb)
{
  logger.info("onChanged "+ejb.toString());
}
```

But unfortunately the `onChanged` is only invoked in the `@SessionScoped` Bean which belongs to the current user session. But I want to reach also the Beans belonging to other users sessions. Is this possible with this CDI event handling?

Comment: take a look at this one [extending-cdi-observer-pattern-to-support-global-events/](http://blog.akquinet.de/2012/02/28/extending-cdi-observer-pattern-to-support-global-events/) it might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Ravi Thanks for this blog entry, can you please provide your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution as described by Markus Dahm in his blog entry [here](http://blog.akquinet.de/2012/02/28/extending-cdi-observer-pattern-to-support-global-events/)

His solution to send events to all active sessions of the web application involves extending the existing CDI observer pattern to support global events.

Here is the relevant code:

First we need a GlobalevHttpSessionController that registers and handles all HTTP sessions and delegates all events to the sessions:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class GlobalevHttpSessionController {
  public static final String 
    EVENT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "HttpSessionControllerEvent";

  private final List _httpSessions = new ArrayList();

  public List getHttpSessions() {
    return new ArrayList(_httpSessions);
  }

  public void addSession(final HttpSession httpSession) {
    _httpSessions.add(httpSession);
  }

  public void removeSession(final HttpSession httpSession) {
    _httpSessions.remove(httpSession);
  }

  public void fireEvent(final GlobalEvent eventObject) {
    for (final HttpSession session : _httpSessions) {
      fireEvent(session, eventObject);
    }
  }

  private void fireEvent(final HttpSession session, final GlobalEvent eventObject) {
    try {
      final List globalEvents = getGlobalEvents(session);

      globalEvents.add(eventObject);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("fireEvent", e);
    }
  }

  private synchronized List getGlobalEvents(final HttpSession session) {
    List globalEvents = (List) session.getAttribute(EVENT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);

    if (globalEvents == null) {
      globalEvents = new ArrayList();
      session.setAttribute(EVENT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, globalEvents);
    }

    return globalEvents;
  }
}
```

Where GlobalEvent is just a simple serializable super class for all global events:

```
public abstract class GlobalEvent implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

Next, we need an HTTP listener to add and remove active client sessions:

```
@WebListener
public class GlobalevHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
  @Inject
  private GlobalevHttpSessionController _httpSessionController;

  public void sessionCreated(final HttpSessionEvent se) {
    _httpSessionController.addSession(se.getSession());
  }

  public void sessionDestroyed(final HttpSessionEvent se) {
    _httpSessionController.removeSession(se.getSession());
  }
}
```

And to dispatch the events to the clients, he chose to look up incoming events using a JSF PhaseListener. Other solutions, for example using Filters, are also possible.
The listener looks for global events and dispatches them to the local session using the CDI bean manager. The manager instance is obtained via a JNDI lookup (by specification the bean manager has to be bound by the container under java:comp/BeanManager). We cannot use CDI injection here, unfortunately, since the phase listener is not instantiated by CDI, but by the Java Server Faces (JSF) framework. The framework however does supply all the information we need to access the HTTP session via the FacesContext object

```
public class GlobalevEventPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {
  public void beforePhase(final PhaseEvent event) {
    final FacesContext facesContext = event.getFacesContext();
    final HttpSession httpSession =   
        JSFUtil.getHttpSession(facesContext);

    if (httpSession != null) {
      final List globalEvents = getGlobalEvents(httpSession);

      if (!globalEvents.isEmpty()) {
        fireEvents(globalEvents);
      }
    }
  }

  private void fireEvents(final List globalEvents) {
    final BeanManager beanManager = lookBeanManager();

    if (beanManager != null) {
      try {
        for (final GlobalEvent devaGlobalEvent : globalEvents) {
          beanManager.fireEvent(devaGlobalEvent);
        }
      } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("fireEvents", e);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
    return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE; // RESTORE_VIEW;
  }

  private BeanManager lookBeanManager() {
    try {
      final Object obj = 
        new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");

      return (BeanManager) obj;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
           throw new 
            IllegalStateException("Lookup bean manager", e);
    }

    return null;
  }

  private synchronized List getGlobalEvents(final HttpSession httpSession) {
    final List events = (List) httpSession.getAttribute(
        GlobalevHttpSessionController.EVENT_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
    final List result = new ArrayList();

    if (events != null) {
      result.addAll(events);
      events.clear();
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Finally, we need to register our listener in faces-config.xml:

```
<lifecycle>
  <phase-listener>
de.akquinet.jbosscc.globalev.listener.GlobalevEventPhaseListener
  </phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

Code also available on [github](https://github.com/mdahm/jbosscc-globalev)

Thanks to Markus!

Comment: Does the session list needs to be a WeakReference? Or are sessions always cleaned up by the container?

Comment: Great solution for synchronous events! Now with JSF 2.2 it is possible to use injection in PhaseListeners and therefore it should also be possible to fire events asynchronously. An asynchronous observer added to the PhaseListener will be called as expected. But an asynchronous observer added to a different SessionScoped bean will not be called! Are there any limitations in your approach for asynchronous events and observers?

Answer (score 0):

I thought of this once but then, how scalable is this approach? What if you had thousands of active sessions? The callback method for the event would have to be very lightweight as you'd have thousands of method calls in each one of the contexts for every event you fire.

You don't always need to notify all the active sessions, you could extend this mechanism and have certain sessions subscribe to a particular event so the number of method calls is under your control.

Much of what you should do depends on your requirements, if the data is updated very frequently, you are better off having the session bean poll the application scoped bean for changes, this way, the session bean only refreshes its data upon an actual request from the user. This will keep up to date only those beans which are currently consuming data.

Again, maybe someone can help me out with this but I feel this will not lead to a scalable design, what if one day you decide to use load balancing and you have a cluster of servers and you need to propagate an event to all active sessions in all the servers etc. I feel the spec did not implement this for a valid reason. You should minimize the workload of your server to what the user requires, think how many session beans you could be updating with your event that belong to users who left their computers to go for a cup of coffee, etc.